# How can I count the number of keys with same values in a map, and store it?

Tags: flutter, dart

Little backgroud of the app:

I'm building an app that let users book a seat for a whole day, the user will selects a date then the app will display how many seats are left for that day, if its 1 or greater the user can book, once he clicks on book it will put his name or userId next to a seat then push it to firebase.

From this approach the user doesn't have the choice of selecting which seats, so it will assign the next free seat available.

Any suggestions for a new method or way for storing and retrieving data?

This method is first that came to my mind.

I have a **map** that store the seats and each user that booked a seat

```
 Map<dynamic, dynamic> booking = {
'seat1':'john',
'seat2': null,
'seat3': null,
'seat4': null,
'seat5': null,
'seat6': null,
'seat7': null,};
```

and here to store the seats left

```
  int freeSeats = 0;
```

What's the correct way of counting? With my basic knowledge I went with **forEach** in combination with a for loop to count how many null in that map but I failed miserably, I couldn't find a way to count when the values are null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find a way, desperate solution but it works ¯_(ツ)_/¯

first I convert the map 'values' into a list

```
var list = booking.values.toList();
```

then count the occurrence of the value and store it

```
freeSeats = list.where((e) => e == null).length;
```

Comment: Not sure why you would need to do that given my solution and comments, but each to there own.

Comment: It was more a reply to the initial question in the title. your answer is correct for the application case.

Comment: Ok. I understand and you are correct. Apologies for my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would go with knowing how many seats there are in total and only storing occupied seats in your map . There is not much point in storing nulls in a map. Then you can just check the length of the map (booking.length) to see how many seats are occupied and therefore how many seats are still available.

**Update**
Having posted my answer, I did consider that I don't really know your use case. If you want to have a grid of seats, in your UI, that shows available seats as well as those booked then it may be simpler to fully populate your seat map with all possible seats, including nulls, and use that map to build your GridView. In that UI example you don't need to know, in the app, the next available seat, you just make occupied seats non-selectable.

Comment: great approach, anyway to generate the keys based on the previous past seat number and stop at 7?

Comment: Having posted my answer, I did consider that I don't really know your use case. If you want to have a grid of seats, in your UI, that shows avaliable seats then you will need to fully populate your seat map with all possible seats and use that map to build your GridView. In that UI example you don't need to know in the app the next available seat, you just make occupied seats non-selectable. It is difficult for me to second guess how you intend to process the map.

Comment: You probably need to expand on what you are trying to achieve (the realworld purpose, not the programming bit) and then you will get other people's view hopefully.

Comment: Well the idea is pretty much basic, the user selects a date, then it indicates how many seats are left, if there is 1 or more left he can then click on the book botton and his name will be added next to a seat then upload the whole map to firebase. If the next user selects the same date the map will be downloaded and so on. I wanted to have a UI where users can selects their sests but my experience in programming is limited for now.

Comment: So if you are always giving the person the next available seat sequentially then, based on my initial answer, booking.length plus 1 gives you the next available seat. You then just need to check that there are still seats available.

Comment: I will definitely try your approach! its straightforward.  I will update my post with more background. Thanks alot for your time.

Comment: Np. Maybe look at this for the seat grid UI. It is only a proof of concept but could help you, with some work. https://github.com/egyleader/Flutter-Movie-Ticket-App